# Does growth plate fusion correlate with finishing linear bone growth?

Tags: bones

I know that complete growth plate fusion [happens on average between ages 15–20 for girls (with the most common being 15–18 years for girls) and 17–24 for boys (with the most common being 18–22 years for boys)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphyseal_plate).

However, I couldn't find any sources for a related question: Does growth plate fusion also correlate with finishing linear bone growth?

Any answers with references are highly appreciated.